# Java replaceall ignore case and special characters

Tags: java, regex, character

This is just an example code of the thing i try to accomplish.

```
String s = "hello(1234aA)something";
String replaceString = "(1234aa)";
String s2 = s.replaceAll("(i?)" + replaceString, "something");
```

The String s is going to be the same but can differ in case, thats why i use (i?) in replaceall.
How can i make regex ignore the special

Comment: What should s2 look like after the replacement, in your opinion?

Comment: made a little misstake with the replacementstring, i have edited the code here now, but i still wont work.

Comment: I found a way to fix it, using the "\\Q" in the beginning of the replace string and "\\E" in the end.

Comment: ah, got it, tricky one, voting up, you expect "hellosomethingsomething" I presume?

Comment: Darn, it should be "(?i)", you put me on the wrong foot there, then it should work with just `Pattern.quote(String) : String`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`quote()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote%28java.lang.String%29), it seems you've already figured out the ignore case, but you should use (?i), not (i?).

```
String s = "hello(1234aA)something";
String replaceString = "(?i)" + Pattern.quote("(1234aa)");
String s2 = s.replaceAll(replaceString, "something");
```

This should work.

Comment: The `quote()` method does not seem to do much more than to add "\Q" and "\E" at the beginning and end, but it's always better to use methods if they have been defined in the API specifically for this case, so the asker was on the right track already.